# How to use a python package in inline-python

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

A few days ago I came across by [inline-python](https://github.com/fusion-engineering/inline-python), which uses rust macro system to make developers able to write python code in rust, and uses PyO3 to do so, Im wondering is there a way to easily import packages of PyPi, without including their file in project code by hand, and building them on my own in a inline-python Context, because it seems like its bounding python in the executable and not using system python, or at least not using system and user installed packages

something like:

```rust
use inline_python::python;
fn main() {
    python! {
        import textual
    }
}
```

And I want to know is it dynamic linking python libs or static linking it? or maybe some other trick?

p.s.: I want to know its possible or not, I'm not looking to know is it a good idea or not, cause I guess its not, but if you have an idea closely equivalents to it, please comment it, something like use rust libs, is not close!